# How do i remove the least score compared to "student id" and "homework "in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I want to remove the least score using the `type: homework and student_id`.
For Example,
`student_id :0` have two values i.e type:homework
and i want to remove the least one i.e

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 14.8504576811645 }
```

---

**My File:**

```
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "exam", "score" : 54.6535436362647 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb578" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 31.95004496742112 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 14.8504576811645 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57a" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 63.98402553675503 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57b" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "exam", "score" : 74.20010837299897 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57c" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 96.76851542258362 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57d" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 21.33260810416115 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57e" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 44.31667452616328 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57f" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "exam", "score" : 19.88180838833524 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb580" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 1.528220212203968 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb581" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "homework", "score" : 60.9750047106029 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb582" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "homework", "score" : 97.75889721343528 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({
    "student_id": 0,
    "type": "homework"
}).sort({
    "score": 1
}).limit(1).
forEach(function(data) {

    db.getCollection('home').remove({
        _id: data._id
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works.. only changes...is db.getCollection('collectionName').remove(

Comment: i have 1 million records to delete how do i increment the student_id...?

Comment: if you want delete least score record in all student with "type:homework" , you just remove student_id condition in find query.